# recode_factor cannot replace missing values

Tags: r, forcats

I've got an issue with recode_factor function. For some reason, I can't replace NAs with 'missing'.

Here is my attempt

```
recode_factor(Data$i_ypsocweb, `1` = "yes", `2` = "no", missing = "missing")
```

The values aren't replaced and I'm seeing an error

> NAs introduced by coercionUnreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not
>   compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply
>   .default

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2f5a.png)

What's even worse, when I axtually open the data set and find the value, it hasnt been changed. I still get numerical values

Comment: See `?forcats::fct_explicit_na`. If you need further help, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There is no sample data, but one of these should get what you need.  Sample data below where `x` is a numerical array and `y` is a factor.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), size = 15, replace = TRUE)
y <- as.factor(x)

x %>% recode(`1` = "yes", `2` = "no", .missing = "missing")
[1] "yes"     "missing" "yes"     "no"      "yes"     "missing" "missing" "no"      "no"      "missing" "missing"
[12] "yes"     "yes"     "yes"     "no"

case_when(y == 1 ~ "yes", y == 2 ~ "no", is.na(y) ~ "missing")
[1] "yes"     "missing" "yes"     "no"      "yes"     "missing" "missing" "no"      "no"      "missing" "missing"
[12] "yes"     "yes"     "yes"     "no"
```